# Removing stop codons from alignment file for dn/ds calculation

Tags: phylogenetics, perl

This is one of the [question](https://www.biostars.org/p/65618/#443249) which is very similar to my problem or almost same to my problem

I ran with dummy data nucleotide [alignment](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XfmKO4GZPsSNonhcpwVK5iN5LDd-LS4L/view?usp=sharing) and the amino [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gbBgaGNOrXgVjZzNxvNCizLq0n3LL5Lj/view?usp=sharing) it works perfectly fine,i can run the dn/ds from phangorn without any issue.

But when i ran with my data nucleotide [alignment](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I_8eCQlNG0r3vdVpkoGmKJEatmovgF9z/view?usp=sharing) and the amino [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kJapQ9UyCPnIr8uIkLi8zrvlT5NGCj-d/view?usp=sharing) I do get this warning

```
In kaks(carps) : sequence lengths are not a multiple of 3
```

and error.

The [code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14s4YnTPoQPL0fkGxNEklUYrhPoyhxh4C/view?usp=sharing)

Any help or suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I would align your sequences with the software available here: https://github.com/veg/hyphy-analyses/tree/master/codon-msa

Comment: That is a good approach and very up to date answer.

Comment: thank you i will try this out as well

Comment: post-msa.bf  is it like shell script? im seeing this extension for the first time